# Long response time when calling a service in a Docker container with Apache Camel

Tags: java, rest, docker, spring-boot, apache-camel

I'm running Apache Camel v2.17 with Spring Boot (v1.2.8) and three microservices (also Spring Boot) in four seperate docker containers.

My Camel app exposes a REST service that accepts three request parameters (one for each microservice). Each parameter is then send to its corresponding microservice. The response of each microservice will then be aggregated in the response body of the Camel REST service.

Here my route for better understanding:

```
public void configure() {
    restConfiguration().component("restlet").port(8080).bindingMode(RestBindingMode.auto);

    rest("/api/v0.1").get("/aggregated")
        .param().name("service1Id").dataType("long").required(false).endParam()
        .param().name("service2Id").dataType("long").required(false).endParam()
        .param().name("service3Id").dataType("long").required(false).endParam()
    .route()
        .split(header(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY).tokenize("&"), new ServiceResultAggregator())
        .choice()
        .when().method("routingHelper", "isRequiredIdKey(*, 'service1Id')")
            .to("direct:dynamic")
        .when().method("routingHelper", "isRequiredIdKey(*, 'service2Id')")
            .to("direct:dynamic")
        .when().method("routingHelper", "isRequiredIdKey(*, 'service3Id')")
            .to("direct:dynamic")
        .otherwise()
            .bean("routingHelper", "clearBody")
        .endChoice()
    .end();

    from("direct:dynamic").process("eurekaProcessor")
        .toD("restlet:${header.serviceUrl}${header.serviceValue}?bridgeEndpoint=true&throwExceptionOnFailure=false";
}
```

The `eurekaProcessor` gets the respective service from a eureka server and writes its url into the message header.

#### Now my problem:

When I call the Camel REST service with my docker setup, the request time to each service takes around 5 seconds. [Link to logfile](http://pastebin.com/fhLymTF1)

However if I run all services on my local machine without docker, the response time is much shorter. Also calling the services directly with curl on their docker IP like so:

```
curl http://172.18.0.5:8080/api/service1/1234
```

works like a charm.

All the Dockerfiles look much the same:

```
FROM ubuntu-image
COPY target/service.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

I build my docker containers with docker-compose:

```
version: '2'
services:
    eureka:
        build: ../EurekaServer/
        ports:
         - "8761:8761"

    service1:
        build: ../Microservice1/

    service2:
        build: ../Microservice2/

    service3:
        build: ../Microservice3/

    camel:
        build: ../CamelAPIGateway/
        ports:
         - "8080:8080"
```

Has anyone encountered the same problem and/or knows the reason (and hopefully a solution) for this behavior?

#### Edit:

When I call the microservices (in docker container) with Camel on my local machine (no docker container) the response time is the same as if Camel would run inside a docker container.

Also I logged the neat *Message History* (that you get when camel gets an uncaught exception) for each exchange in my ServiceResultAggregator class:

```
Message History
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RouteId              ProcessorId          Processor                                                                        Elapsed (ms)
[route1            ] [route1            ] [http://0.0.0.0:8080/api/aggregated?restletMethods=GET                         ] [      5196]
[route1            ] [choice1           ] [when[bean{routingHelper}]choice[when[bean{routingHelper}]choice[when[bean{rout] [      5106]
[route1            ] [bean1             ] [bean[ref:routingHelper method:prepareHeader]                                  ] [         0]
[route1            ] [to1               ] [direct:dynamic                                                                ] [      5087]
[route5            ] [process1          ] [ref:eurekaProcessor                                                           ] [        24]
[route5            ] [log1              ] [log                                                                           ] [         1]
[route5            ] [toD1              ] [                                                                              ] [      5061]
[route1            ] [bean2             ] [bean[ref:responseWrapper method:wrapServiceResponse]                          ] [         1]
```

Just in case you are wondering... `bean1`and `bean2` don't show in my example route code to keep it as simple as possible.

The same History when I run everything without any docker container:

```
Message History
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RouteId              ProcessorId          Processor                                                                        Elapsed (ms)
[route1            ] [route1            ] [http://0.0.0.0:8079/api/aggregated?restletMethods=GET                         ] [        13]
[route1            ] [choice1           ] [when[bean{routingHelper}]choice[when[bean{routingHelper}]choice[when[bean{rout] [        13]
[route1            ] [bean1             ] [bean[ref:routingHelper method:prepareHeader]                                  ] [         0]
[route1            ] [to1               ] [direct:dynamic                                                                ] [        10]
[route5            ] [process1          ] [ref:eurekaProcessor                                                           ] [         0]
[route5            ] [log1              ] [log                                                                           ] [         0]
[route5            ] [toD1              ] [                                                                              ] [        10]
[route1            ] [bean2             ] [bean[ref:responseWrapper method:wrapServiceResponse]                          ] [         1]
```

Comment: I'd eliminate the issue one by one. Add expose statements to your compose file for every microservice and check if they are the bottleneck or your camel setup. From the log file it looks like its taking time cause the containers are still starting up when the request comes in.

Comment: Since I have EXPOSE in every Dockerfile I don't need to do that in the docker-compose too, do I? (At least it works without) If I send a request with `curl` the response time from each service container is just a couple of ms. If I call the rest service in the camel container, it takes 5 sec for camel to send a request to a service container. `Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'` only comes the first time after startup. But the long response time stays.

Comment: Ok, but did you curl it from outside or in the container itself? So if the request itself is fast I'd eliminate Eureka as the issue. Could also be that your problem lies within resolving the service endpoints.

Comment: I can't curl from the inside because it's not installed on the image I use (and I can't install it). The only thing I can do is ping (The response there takes from 50 to 100 ms). Eliminating Eureka by using static endpoints yields the same result as with. The communication (registration and service fetching) with eureka is fine by the way. Must be something wrong with my route I guess.

Comment: Ok, then the issue is really your docker-compose file. Cause looking at to log file the services you are calling are only starting up seconds (between 5 and 15) after Camel is creating the request. Bear with me I don't have too much knowledge about camel. But does that also happen when you issue a second request to camel? Maybe after having the whole setup already running for some time, e.g. 60 seconds? You should also be able to check using actuators health endpoint.

Comment: Yes and No. **Yes**, if I issue the second request about a minute after the first, the response takes nearly the same. **No**, if I issue the second request right after the first, it only takes some ms (because the connection is still cached somewhere I suppose). Like I said, the Initialization only takes place on the very first request. Also the services register with eureka, so they are doing something before Camel calls them. I updated my Question a little and added the message history for the exchange. Maybe it's the restlet protocol? (Although it is using the Apache HTTP client ...)

Comment: Hmm but the connection to the second service can't be cached from the first one. So from the log it really looks like the container is only started when the request comes in. But I have no explanation for this since docker and camel are nor linked and don't know about each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by using [servlet](http://camel.apache.org/servlet.html) for the `restConfiguration` and [http](http://camel.apache.org/http.html) as protocol for the microservice endpoint:

```
restConfiguration().component("servlet").port(8080).bindingMode(RestBindingMode.auto);
// [...]
from("direct:dynamic").process("eurekaProcessor")
    .toD("${header.serviceUrl}${header.serviceValue}?bridgeEndpoint=true&throwExceptionOnFailure=false");
```

Since the protocol of `${header.serviceUrl}` is already `http` I don't need to add it explicitly.

But I still find it odd, that the restlet protocol takes ages in my docker setup...